# MySql Azure in android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, azure

I am writing an application for android . there is a need to create a database . There mySql database in MS Azure. But here's how to record the data from the application and read them do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Azure Mobile Services.  It's a service that let you expose a database thru a REST API (among other other things).
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/mobile/

Here's a link to a Getting Started page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/

Comment: there is need paid subscription , it does not suit me

Comment: You can use the free tier and a free 20MB SQL Database. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/mobile-services/

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, we usually have two solutions.

1.The one is  Azure mobile service. If you want to use MySQL database, You just use C# backend mobile service. Because we can custom the Database connection on mobile service website.

Please see this [Page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started-data/).

As client, we can use below code to connect Mobile service and table:

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
         "https://**.azure-mobile.net/",
         "**",
         this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());

            // Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use

           mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);
```

2.Another one is that we can build  web service and host on Azure hosting service(such as Web APP, Cloud Service and VM). 
But we need spend time to build the service and code logic.

Client app can handle data via web service.

As we known, currently if you want to use MySQL database, you need subscribe it from Azure Store. 
However you can install MySQL on VM, please refer to this [tutorials](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-mysql-windows-server-2008r2/)

Answer (score -1):

You can create your WebService and call this with REST API, and for save it on your mobile application, your can use SugarORM take a look: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/